# How to force y-axis to show density in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have a plot whose y-axis I need to show density instead of frequency.

This is the code I use:

```r
ggplot(stocks_orig, aes(x=Value)) + geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), colour="black", fill="white", bins=20)+geom_density(aes(y=..density..),alpha=.2, fill="lightblue", size=1)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = -0.019), linetype = "dashed", size = 1, color = "blue") + annotate("text", x =0.0, y = 51, label ="number1")+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = -0.029), linetype = "dotted", size = 1, color = "blue") + annotate("text", x =-0.051, y = 25, label = "number2")+ 
  labs(title="Title", subtitle="subtitle", caption="Caption")
```

And this is the plot I get, which shows frequency instead, despite using  `aes(y=..density..)`:

[image]

This is my data:

```
> dput(stocks_orig[1:10,])
structure(list(Date = structure(c(14613, 14614, 14615, 14616, 
14617, 14620, 14621, 14622, 14623, 14624), class = "Date", tzone = "Europe/Prague"), 
    Growth = c(0.0139029051689914, -0.001100605444033, -0.000800320170769155, 
    -0.000300045009001992, 0.00359353551013022, 0.00169855663558151, 
    -0.00662187630888697, 0.00836491633162767, 0.00259662584726591, 
    -0.00944445882799969), Medium = c(0.0181345701954827, 0.00458945233380722, 
    0.00159872136369707, 0.00697561373642514, 0.00409161790325356, 
    0.000699755114273265, -0.0108587433348759, 0.00717420374800045, 
    0.00119928057548219, -0.0118701725704874), Value = c(0.0273232956488904, 
    0.0134096869099177, 0.0061808590750811, 0.0120273802127185, 
    0.000499875041650993, -0.000800320170769155, -0.021938907518754, 
    0.0119285708652738, 0.00379279823869626, -0.0170444346092585
    )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000024c38fd1ef0>)
```

Comment: I think it is showing density, in the sense that the total area under the curve will be 1. It looks different than you expected because the x axis is so narrow, most of it in a range < 0.05. This means that the average y value for the curve would be ~20, so it makes sense that the peak is nearly 50. Since your bins are currently 1/120th wide, one approach could be to scale your density values down to 1/120th so the bins heights total 1.

Comment: That's right. Check out `hist(stocks_orig$Value, probability = T)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure this isn't a density? For a curve to be a density it has to satisfy three rules (for a more mathematical explanation see e.g. [this](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/14/14.1))

1. It can't be negative. Your histogram + density curve appear to satisfy this rule
2. The area underneath the curve has to integrate too one. This also appears to be satisfied. As a rough indication, you could draw a triangle between (0, -0.025), (0,0.025) & (40, 0) and observe that this triangle (which has area 1) and your density curve are very similar.
3. You should be able to integrate only some interval of your density curve, which is immediately satisfied due to the continuity of your curve.

To also see this graphically I included an example. Notice how a decrease in the range of x, causes the y-axis to increase (since the area needs to be one):

```
ggplot(NULL, aes(x = rnorm(5000))) +
  geom_density(aes(y=..density..), size = 1)
```

[image: standard normal density curve]

```
ggplot(NULL, aes(x = rnorm(5000, sd = 0.1))) +
  geom_density(aes(y=..density..), size = 1)
```

[image: another normal density curve]

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are expecting the bin heights to add to one, and for the density curve to follow the same scaling. The default behavior is different, and is designed so that the area under the curve will total to 1. This means that for narrow x ranges, the peak density can be much higher than 1. To make it so that the total heights of the bins add to 1, you can scale the output by the bin width (which you can control more directly using `binwidth` than `bins`).

Compare:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes((wt-3)/100)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), binwidth = 1/120) +
  geom_density(aes(y=..density..))
```

[image]

and

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes((wt-3)/100)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density../120), binwidth = 1/120) +
  geom_density(aes(y=..density../120))
```

[image]